# Local git clone is ahead of origin even though no local changes were made

Tags: git, deployment, chef-infra

We use Git to manage and deploy code. I'm on the Ops team and I do deployments. Our developers make changes and push code into Github, and we (Ops) use some managed processes to pull production code and deploy it.

The process is like this:

Background

- Developers do stuff. That stuff ends up in Github and the Devs tell us so.
- We have a local "staging" clone, and a local "deployment" bare git repo. The local git clone has two remotes, Github as "origin" and the local bare repo as "deploy"
- We use chef on the web servers to actually deploy the code via the chef git resource that pulls from the "deploy" remote
- We have the "deploy" remote so that there is a gating mechanism between Dev finishing stuff and our deployment timing. (Rather than deploying from Github directly)

Actual deploy Process

1. `cd into local clone`
2. `git checkout branchname`
3. `git pull origin branchname`
4. `git push deploy branchname`

All of this is partially automated, and is moving to full automation. As such, we are careful to not ever make local changes to the staging clone, and we expect that the output of `git status` in that clone will only ever be `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`

**However**, we had a weird message come up this week. The deploy clone is stating that it is **80 commits ahead** of origin! Even though it also says `nothing to commit`.

```
# On branch branchname
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branchname' by 80 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Finally, there isn't really a problem, per se. The commit SHA256 hash matches in this clone, and on the deployed code on all of the web servers. I didn't do an actual rsync comparison, but I'm pretty confident that the actual code itself is deployed correctly.

**I want to know how this could happen, if it is bad, and how to clean it up short of deleting the local clone and starting over.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both `deploy` and `local` repos have been cloned from the same '`origin`' (GitHub), your process shows that only `local` is doing a `git pull origin`.

The repo `deploy` never fetches anything from `origin` (it only receives commits from `local`).
That means `deploy` still believe having commit that would not be on origin (at least the origin it knows about).
A simple `git fetch origin` executed from the `deploy` repo would make that status cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a variety of reasons why this could have happened, such as `origin/branchname` having been reset to a previous commit, or someone having pulled an `another_repo/branchname` in the local repo by mistake. However, you seem to have misunderstood what the message actually means.

Imagine the following commits:

```
A -- B -- C -- D                origin/branchname
      \         \
        E ------ F -- G -- H    branchname
```

Now if you haven't touched the local repository, then obviously it is clean and you get the `nothing to commit (working directory clean)` message. However, `branchname` is indeed ahead of `origin/branchname` by 3 commits. This simply means that you have 3 commits in your current branch after the head of `origin/branchname`. Of course, there is still nothing to commit! (While there *is* something to push. These two are different)

This is one possible scenario of how this could have happened:

```
                  E -- F        origin/otherbranch
                /       \
A -- B -- C -- D         \      origin/branchname
                \         \
                 --------- G    branchname
```

If you have (by mistake for example) said:

```
git checkout branchname
git pull origin otherbranch
```

Then you have 2 commits in `branchname` that are ahead of `origin/branchname`.

Again, you need more analysis to know what exactly has happened. Maybe a `git log --pretty=oneline --graph` would help find the problem. Once you have done so, you can try to reset back to a proper previous state.

Comment: I believe the status message was about the '`deploy`' repo, not the '`local`' one. In which case, the explanation I give in my answer seems quite simpler and straight-forward (`deploy` never refreshed its `origin` remote branch)

Comment: @vonc, I doubt that: _... we are careful to not ever make local changes to **the staging clone**, and we expect that the output of "git status" in **that clone** will only ever be "nothing to commit (working directory clean)"

However, we had a weird message ..._

Comment: The very next words of your extract are... "The **`deploy`** clone is stating that it is 80 commits ahead of `origin`!". Hence my answer. But no worries. Between your answer and mine, we are covering *all the cases* ;)

Comment: @vonc, ah I see. The question doesn't seem to give enough information though. Anyway, I tried to explain what the message meant in principle. It's his own job to figure out what exactly had happened :D